# Add historical version(s) of files in the current workspace

Tags: perforce

For a long time, we have maintained SQL DDL scripts to create relational schemas.
Those scripts have moved in places in the code base (as code was refactored), and
are updated *in place*, i.e. the workspace contains only the latest version of each schema.

We also have upgrade scripts to go from version N to version (N+1), per-schema.
Those are (mostly) immutable, and accumulate in the workspace, all of them available.

Now we want to add tests that check upgrades of older schemas, via the upgrade scripts,
to verify they match what the latest version of each schema produces. But for that,
we need to have access to historical versions of the old schemas, to instantiate them,
upgrade them, and compare them to the latest.

We can easily add copies of the legacy released SQL DDL scripts (via `p4 copy` or not),
but I think some kind of *symbolic* link to the original artefact, via its legacy path name (
and revision?), to generate in the current workspace under a different name would be better.

Is it possible to do something like this in Perforce?

1. The main benefit is that it guarantees we are using the correct
   artifact from the historical release branch.
2. The second (minor) benefit is that the file takes almost no place in the repo,
   since the file content is basically already in the repo.
3. A nice third benefit, if possible, would be for the file to NOT
   be editable (i.e. be immutable). One could update the *link* to a different artifact,
   but since the goal is to see a historical revision of an artifact,
   the content of that artifact should NOT be editable by users, ideally.

A related question is whether the revision needs to be explicit, or we can use the latest version is a given branch (since each release is its own branch)?

Maybe it's a silly question, since the artifact's repo path includes the branch. I'm no Perforce expert, so please assume only basic Perforce knowledge from me. TIA, --DD

PS: We are on Windows and Linux, so an actual *Perforce symlink* might not work too well on Windows?

```
$ p4 -V
...
Rev. P4/LINUX26X86_64/2017.1/1738874 (2018/12/07).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use `p4 copy`.

- It gives you a branched file with whatever symbolic name you want that will be synced down into the workspace with no fuss.
- A branched file takes up no space in the depot (Perforce "lazy-copies" files on the back end when they're copied/branched via an integration action).  As far as the Perforce server is concerned, copies *are* links; they just don't look that way to the end user.
- If you need to make the new file uneditable, that's pretty easy to accomplish via protections.

An example of making a copy from an old rev might be:

```
p4 copy file.txt@1234 file_at_change_1234.txt
```

Obviously you can copy to a different directory, you can name the copy whatever you want, and you can specify the revision however you want (it can be a date, it can be a revision number, it can be a label, you name it).

You could potentially also accomplish this type of file duplication within the workspace with tricky client maps (the "ditto map" and "ChangeView" features would be the relevant things to mess around with), but that's much less user friendly IMO.

Comment: OK, I'll go for simple them, and follow your advice. I've only ever copied files currently in the repo / branch / workspace, not historical ones no longer in the workspace, so if you can also demonstrate how to do that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding "protections", that's the first time I hear about them. I don't control the server, I'm just a regular client, so I cannot do anything admin-related. So any guidance regarding those would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you're not an admin it's probably not worth going down that road, but if you do `p4 help protect` or google "Perforce protections" that should be enough to give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think what you want might be ditto mapping, aka import&
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4guide/Content/P4Guide/streams.paths.html

With the one-to-many mapping you can specify revision numbers so you can map different past versions to different file paths (as read-only).

Comment: Thanks. We are not using streams, thus I don't think this applies? Also, even if we did, devs create their own specs (to pick and choose high-level folders for their workspaces) and/or specs are script-generated. So anything that relies on "fine-grained" spec-engineering is not a good fit here I'm afraid.